# How to get SDK logs dor ReactNative MobilePush SDK?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, react-native

we are almost done with MobilePush implementation in our app, which is built on React, hence we use the ReactSDK Plugin.

Everything works fine - contacts are getting registered, optins/optouts are being noted as expected, messages get sent. However the one thing that doesn't work is knowing that an open has happened, even thought we have SDK Analytics enabled. Support require logs but they are not assisting me in getting the SDK logs? Can someone please help me as the documentation on React Plugin is quite limited.

Tried to call the MCReactModule logSDK State but no idea where the logs are and how extract them.

Answer (score 0):

Enable logging: https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk#mcreactmoduleenableverboselogging

Output the SDK's state: https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/react-native-marketingcloudsdk#mcreactmodulelogsdkstate

The logs are in the LogCat https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/logcat

Launch your app, send yourself a push, click the notification, background the app, capture the logs.

Comment: Yeah, if I could google to find an answer, I would not be posting here.

Comment: "View logs with LogCat -- Android Developers" https://bit.ly/3SgEvuE

Comment: How does it not have anything to do with Salesforce or code? Also, sending a google search is a quite condescending thing to do to someone just looking for a bit of help, don't you think?

Comment: Sorry if it came across that way. When something "logs" in Android you should check the logcat. Hope the link helped.